# Programar reinicio automático de mi dispositvo Android

Tags: android

A través de código estoy intentando que mi dispositivo se reinicie a las 3.00 AM. Para ello he usado [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)  de la siguiente manera:

```
  private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
  private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...

  private void sReboot() {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResetApp.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);


}
```

La clase a la que llama el PendingIntent es la siguiente:

```
 public class ResetApp extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("test", "entra");
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su", "-c", "reboot now"});
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

En el AndroidMainfest también he agregado el receiver

```
 <receiver android:name=".ExampleActivity$ResetApp"></receiver>
```

El problema es simple: cuando llega a la hora, no se ejecuta la clase

Comment: El problema puede ser tanto dentro de la clase como fuera. Para saberlo es importante que muestres el log de tu aplicación al momento de ejecutarse la alarma. Una forma muy buena de saber que parte del codigo no se esta ejecutando, es agregando `Log.i()` en diferentes partes de tu aplicación.

Comment: Obviamente ya he hecho varios log.i. Nunca llega a entrar en la clase

Comment: Proporcionas muy poca información para saber cual es el origen del problema. Como te dije antes, agrega el **logcat** del momento en que tiene que ejecutarse la alarma y agrega el código completo de la clase desde donde llamas la alarma.

Comment: Como comenta @David es importante revisar el LogCat, el problema se encuentra en el  método para reiniciar el dispositivo ya que tu dispositivo requiere permisos de Root para poder reiniciar programaticamente

Answer (score 1):

El código para llamar el `BroadcastReceiver` me parece correcto, únicamente asegura que tengas definido el mismo dentro del tag `<application>` de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application>
  ...
  ...
  <receiver android:name=".ResetApp"></receiver>

</application>
```

El problema principal se encuentra en el método que usas para reiniciar el dispositivo, seguramente tu dispositivo no tiene permisos Root, ya que **este método únicamente funciona en dispositivos que tienen permisos Root**

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su", "-c", "reboot now"});
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Si. Mi dispositivo es root.

Comment: Si es así, revisa que error se muestra al imprimir el stacktrace en  : e1.printStackTrace(); probablemente la estructura de archivos de tu dispositivo es diferente, te aconsejo trates también con:  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/xbin/su","-c","reboot"});   y Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot"});

Comment: Si ejecuto ese comando tal cual está al iniciar la app reinicia el dispositivo sin problemas.